# YAML Parsing Issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an issue on Elastic Beanstalk deployment which is:

```
YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /var/app/ondeck/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 2 column 1 /var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>' /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/bundle:23:in `load' /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by: Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 2 column 1 /var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>' /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/bundle:23:in `load' /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>' Tasks: TOP => environment (See full trace by running task with --trace).
```

As what I have read, this is because YAML forbids using tabs, instead it uses spaces.

The problem is that I manually checked every YAML file for tabs, and never found one. I think I missed something **so my question is**: is there any script that can go through my entire source code replacing tabs with 2 spaces in every YAML file?

Comment: You don't need to check every file. Check '/var/app/ondeck/config/database.yml' only.

Comment: I did, but it never got solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s ruby after all: it’s easier and faster to write the script rather than ask questions on SO and google for it.

```
Dir['*/**/*.yml'].each do |f| 
  File.write(f, File.read(f).gsub(/\t/, '  '))
end
```

Comment: You are very right about writing a script on my own :)